# Given a dictionary, how do I join the key and value with "_" and append them into a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I have the following:

```
def dict_join_key_value(input_dict):
    for key,value in input_dict.items():
        y=[]
        x=key+'_'+value
        print(y.append(x))
    return 
dict_join_key_value({"a": "b", "c": "d"})
```

Somehow i was not able to produce the list ['a_b','c_d'], what changes do I need to make to my code?

Comment: you're resetting your list every time.  move the ```y=[]``` outside the for loop

Comment: also, you're not returning ```y```

Comment: Don't reset the list to an empty list in each loop. Also, don't print the return value of `append`. And return `y`.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out int the comments, the following will work:

```
def dict_join_key_value(input_dict):
    y = []
    for key,value in input_dict.items():
        x = key + '_' + value
        y.append(x)
    return y

dict_join_key_value({"a": "b", "c": "d"})
```

You could shorten it in a comprehension:

```
def dict_join_key_value(input_dict):
    return [k + '_' + v for k, v in input_dict.items()]
```

Or using `map`:

```
def dict_join_key_value(input_dict):
    return list(map('_'.join, input_dict.items()))
```